# How to Provide Query Parameters For Azure Log Analytics REST API

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics, azure-data-explorer, kql

I am using [Azure Log Analytics REST API](https://dev.loganalytics.io/) to query data from Azure Log Analytics workspace using the Kusto query language. Kusto provides a way to prevent query injection by using query parameters as documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/queryparametersstatement?pivots=azuredataexplorer). However I am unable to find a way to provide those query parameters for Azure Log Analytics REST API.
Is there a way to achieve this with the Azure Log Analytics REST API or that support is yet to come?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, this feature is not supported yet in Azure Log Analytics rest api. You can raise a feature request in the [user feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/267889-azure-monitor-log-analytics).

Comment: Yes. The feature is not available yet.

Comment: I have already requested this feature.
https://feedback.azure.com/forums/267889-azure-monitor-log-analytics/suggestions/41875684-need-a-way-to-provide-query-parameters-for-log-ana
Those who require this feature, please upvote the above